# EscapeData string escapes DirectorySeperator and VolumeSeperator

Tags: c#

Is there more better way of doing this ? I want to escape special characters but dont want to escape ":" and "\". `I tried using EscapeUriString but it escaped "\\"and did not escape "$"`

```
E.g->path = "C:\\TestArea\\WorkFlow Documents\\Sample $ Folder\\Storage Folder\\Github Folder\\Sample File.docx";

// This method works but is their more better way of doing it
 public static string EscapeandReplace(string path)
 {
     const string Backspace = "%5C";
     const string VolumeSeperator = "%3A";
     path = Uri.EscapeDataString(path);
     path = Regex.Replace(path, VolumeSeperator, Path.VolumeSeparatorChar.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     return Regex.Replace(path, Backspace, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 }
```

Comment: Special characters in what context? For a path? For a regex? A url? Your method indicates the input is a path, but what is it being used for?

Comment: You could write your regex as `%5C|%3A`. What are you trying to achive with this?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 : path it is being used to save in AWS Object Storage as path of the document

Comment: @jira : How can you tell me in above example ?  path it is being used to save in AWS Object Storage as path of the document

Comment: Do you really need that?  [AWS .NET documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TPutObjectRequest.html) does not mention any escaping

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-key-guidelines